# Symfony 3.0: Set Entities with fields that can have null

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

I have an entity Users that has a field:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default"=false})
   */
  private $activated;
```

On my database this is a not_null value. I want this (mapped) field to be able to accept null values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default"=false}, nullable=true)
  */
  private $activated;
```

For more options check doctrine annotations reference: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html